# Saving to PDF adding blank page

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm trying to create a macro that will allow my end users to click on one macro that will ask them for a PDF file that they would like to add as a new page.  The page is based off a template and have a merged cell in the center for the image.  I'm able to get the new page created as well as get a file explorer window with specific filters opened, but I have a couple questions for this.

1. Is it possible to get the full filepath from the file explorer to be put into a variable to later use during the PDF insertion(as my end users may have PDF's saved in different directories)?

Code for the question:

```
    With fd

        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        ' Set the title of the dialog box.
        .Title = "Please select the file."

        ' Clear out the current filters
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "PDF Files", "*.PDF"
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

        ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
        ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
        ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
        If .Show = True Then
            txtFileName = .SelectedItems(1) 'txtFileName will return the file

        End If
    End With
```

2. Is it possible to insert a PDF image into an excel cell and have it fit the cells dimensions?

Code for the question:

```
tempRow = lastRow + 9
   'Sets the correct row/column
    Set rng = crrntWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & tempRow)
   'This portion is trying to insert the PDF as an OLEObject picture
    crrntWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & tempRow) = crrntWorkbook.Sheets(1).OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=txtFileName,_
    DisplayAsIcon:=False).activate
```

Any help with these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For question 2: see the [`OLEObjects.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobjects.add) documentation, specifically *Top*, *Left*, *Width*, and *Height* parameters.

Comment: @bigben So are the top/left parameters allowed to have variables inserted?  The RNG has the range of the cell I am trying to insert the image into but unfortunately doesn't work

```crrntWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & tempRow) = crrntWorkbook.Sheets(1).OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=txtFileName,

DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=rng, Top:=rng, Width:=670, Height:=725)```

Comment: `rng.Left` and `rng.Top`.

Comment: @bigben The position of the image is now correct, but after trying to set the width and height, it still uses the PDF's native dimensions.  I've tried to set the width:= to 25/200/300(should be about 700 pixels total for the space) as well as to RNG.width.  Should I try to change the dimensions in a new line or how would I go about fixing this?  I apologize, I'm a bit lost when it comes to adding PDF's into excel :(

Comment: @bigben I figured out the solution to it by changing a few lines

```Set rng = crrntWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & tempRow)
    Set oleobj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=txtFileName, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
    With oleobj
        oleobj.Top = rng.Top
        oleobj.Left = rng.Left
        If oleobj.Width > oleobj.Height Then
            oleobj.Width = 550
        Else
            oleobj.Height = 550
        End If
        oleobj.Left = (550 - oleobj.Width) / 3
    End With
```
Thank you very much for your help!